# Balance two same sub-net, same gateway networks openbsd

Tags: networking, routing, openbsd

OPENBSD:

I've two sub-nets 192.168.0.0/24 with the same gateway 192.168.0.1
I've tried to configure two different routing tables, always specify the network adapter and I'm never able to make both to work simultaneously.

If one works the other never routes to the gateway.

I've tested using ping with the interface parameter and aria2c with the interface parameter too. If I have different sub-net it works. Same sub-net one of the gateways gets a weird "link#5" entry on the routing table and it never works.

I know this is a conflict and a corner case... but I'd greatly appreciate ideas. So far, my best idea is to use VMs to connect to the networks, create a NAT on each with different sub-nets and then expose that to the main router... This is far from ideal.

THANKS!

Comment: Thanks. I tought maybe by specifying the interface or using different routing tables it might work, somehow (?). Clearly it's a bad scenario. I can't control the networks, I just happen to have access to multiple wifi networks that I can't reconfigure. IPv6 would solve this but it isn't routing :(

Comment: There is a way you can do it, you need two additional routers. I'll write it up later if I have time. It kind of a hack though

Comment: I'm not sure if ARP can handle two different MAC addresses for the same IP, even if on separate rdomains...